# Getting HSV values of pixels in image OpenCV

Tags: java, image, opencv

I am working on a Rubik's side scanner to determine what state the cube is in. I am quite new to computer vision and using it so it has been a little bit of a challenge. What I have done so far is that I use a video capture and at certain frames capture that frame and save it for image processing. Here is what it looks like.[image]

When the photo is taken the cube is in the same position each time so I don't have to worry about locating the stickers. 
What I am having trouble doing is getting a small range of pixels in each square to determine its HSV.

I know the ranges of HSV are roughly

```
Red = Hue(0...9) AND Hue(151..180)
Orange = Hue(10...15)
Yellow = Hue(16..45)
Green = Hue(46..100)
Blue = Hue(101..150)
White = Saturation(0..20) AND Value(230..255)
```

So after I have captured the image I then load it and split the HSV values of the image but don't know how to get the certain pixel coordinates of the image. How do I do so?

```
    BufferedImage getOneFrame() {
        currFrame++;
        //At the 90th frame I capture that frame and save that frame
        if (currFrame == 120) {
            cap.read(mat2Img.mat);

            mat2Img.getImage(mat2Img.mat);

            Imgcodecs.imwrite("firstImage.png", mat2Img.mat);

        }
        cap.read(mat2Img.mat);

        return mat2Img.getImage(mat2Img.mat);
    }

    public void splitChannels() {

        IplImage firstShot = cvLoadImage("firstImage.png");
        //I split the channels so that I can determine the value of the pixel range
        IplImage hsv = IplImage.create( firstShot.width(), firstShot.height(), firstShot.depth(), firstShot.nChannels());
        IplImage hue = IplImage.create( firstShot.width(), firstShot.height(), firstShot.depth(), CV_8UC1 );
        IplImage sat = IplImage.create( firstShot.width(), firstShot.height(), firstShot.depth(), CV_8UC1 );
        IplImage val = IplImage.create( firstShot.width(), firstShot.height(), firstShot.depth(), CV_8UC1 );


        cvSplit( hsv, hue, sat, val, null );
        //How do I get a small range of pixels of my images to determine get their HSV?

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you know the coordinates of all areas that interest you. Save the information about each area into [cvRect objects](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d0/d76/structCvRect.html).

You can traverse the rectangle area by looping. Make a double loop. In outer loop start at `rect.y` and stop before `rect.y + rect.height`. In inner loop, do a similar thing in x direction. Inside the loop, use [CV_IMAGE_ELEM macro](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/df8/group__core__c.html#ga6c980849bd6bf768b1f2830519bc19b1) to access individual pixel values and compute whatever you need.

One advice though: There are several advantages to using `Mat` instead of `IplImage` when working with OpenCV. I recommend that you start using 'Mat', unless you have some special reasons to do so, of course. [Click to see the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) and take a look at one of constructors that takes one `Mat` and one `Rect` as parameters. This constructor is your good friend - you can create a new `Mat` object (without copying any data) which will only contain the area inside the rectangle.

Comment: There is no specific reason why I use `IplImage` I was using `Mat` before but I couldn't find a way to load a `Mat` image. and split the color channels of that image. Into individual HSV channels.

Comment: Use `imread` and `cvtColor` and the numerous examples found on the web. :) Good luck!

Comment: do I have to use `cvtColor` I already have the image in the format I want.

Comment: no, in that case it is not necessary to use `cvtColor`, sorry for the confusion. :)